# TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation using `apply`

Tags: typescript, this

This question might have been asked before but I am still unable to fix it in my case.

I am trying to write a memoize function in TypeScript but have not been able to type `this` inside of my function

```
function memoize<T extends string | number, R>(fn: (args: T) => R): (args: T) => R {
    const cache: { [key: string]: R } = {};
    return function (...args): R {
        if (cache[args.toString()]) {
            return cache[args.toString()];
        }

        const result = fn.apply(this, args); // TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
        cache[args.toString()] = result;
        return result;
    };
}
```

I get this error

> TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.

And I am not sure I understand how to type `this` and what exactly its type shoud be

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You give `this` a type by having an "argument" named `this` with a type. Since you have no clue what `this` will be (since the person using the function can use it in any context), I'd suggest `unknown` or an explicit `any` type (personally, I think `unknown` is more idiomatic):

```js
function memoize<T extends string | number, R>(fn: (args: T) => R): (args: T) => R {
    const cache: { [key: string]: R } = {};
    return function (this: unknown, ...args): R {
        if (cache[args.toString()]) {
            return cache[args.toString()];
        }

        const result = fn.apply(this, args);
        cache[args.toString()] = result;
        return result;
    };
}
```